# Java: eliminar decimales de un flotat a partir de ciertos digitos

Tags: java, float

Por ejemplo: tengo una formula y me dió 0.083333336, en el resultado final quiero que me aparezca 0.083 y los demás decimales cortarlos/eliminarlos(contando del punto a la derecha que solo queden 3 decimales)

Otro ejemplo:
`float test = 1.1010581944`
Quiero que el resultado final sea `1.101` eliminando 0581944

```
float R1 = Float.parseFloat(args[3]), R2 = Float.parseFloat(args[4]);
float req = R1 + R2; // In ohms
float volts = Float.parseFloat(args[5]);
float intensity = (volts / req); // Quiero cortar los decimales de este resultado
float voltageR1 = (intensity * R1), voltageR2 = (intensity * R2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias formas de hacerlo:

### Usando `Math.Round`:

```
float test = 1.1014581944f;
test = Math.round(test*1000)/1000f;
```

### Usando `BigDecimal`:

```
float test = 1.1010581944f;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(test).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
test = bd.floatValue();
```

### Usando `NumberFormat`:

```
float test = 1.1014581944f;
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
formatter.setRoundingMode( RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
test = new Float(formatter.format(test));
```

Como recomendación, considera usar `double` en lugar de `float` para mejorar la precisión de tus cálculos.